# Javascript not executing procedures correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use JavaScript to manipulate page content in a dummy webpage I'm building.

To that end, I wrote a little function called `writeText(file_name, location)` that gets a HTML file specified by the file name, and prints the content of that file to the `innerHTML` of a pair of `<div>` tags whose id attribute correspond to the `location` field.

I then wrapped the calls in other functions to automate building full pages like this.

So I call something that looks like this:

```
function displayHome() {
    writeText('homeMain.html', 'mainFrame');
    writeText('homeSide.html', 'sideFrame');
}
```

...to display the home page.

However, when I call this function, the display only updates the `'sideFrame'` object and doesn't make any changes to the content of `'mainFrame'`. But if I interrupt the function with an alert("Dummy") between the two `writeText()` calls, then both of the contentFrames update correctly.

I was wondering if anyone has seen anything like this before, and if anyone knows how to fix it.

For completeness' sake (this was copied nearly verbatim from the w3schools website):

```
function writeText(script_file, location) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }   else    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        document.getElementById(location).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
xmlhttp.open("GET",script_file,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Copying verbatim from the w3schools website is already an error.

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools.com, it's full of errors. See http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a global variable xmlhttp, so it gets clobbered the 2nd time the function runs. The request itself is asynchronous, so the second call runs while the first one is still running.

To fix this, use a local variable instead (so each call to the function has its own xmlhttp) by using the "var" keyword before xmlhttp:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}   else    {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Comment: To be more precise, the first call is canceled upon executing `xmlhttp.open()` the second time.